# time.time convert to hours and minutes

Tags: python, discord.py

how to convert time.time to minutes and hours, I need it to write to the database...

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_voice_state_update(self, member, before, after):
    t1 = 0
    t2 = 0
    async with self.bot.db.cursor() as cursor:
        await cursor.execute("SELECT voicetime FROM users WHERE member_id = ? AND guild_id = ?", (member.id, member.guild.id,))
        voicetime = await cursor.fetchone()
        
        try:
            voicetime = voicetime[0]
        except TypeError:
            voicetime = 0
            
        if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None:
            t1 = time.time()
        elif before.channel is not None and after.channel is None:
            t2 = time.time()
            voicetime = t2 - t1
            await cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET voicetime = voicetime + ? WHERE member_id = ? AND guild_id = ?", (voicetime, member.id, member.guild.id,))
        await self.bot.db.commit()
```

Comment: [`from datetime import datetime; datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time())`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```py
import datetime as dt
dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time())
```

This will give you a datetime object